# Nginx configuration, with global defaults and support for a PHP site

Tags: linux, configuration, nginx

The following code is an Nginx default conf file. The conf file itself includes another `server` block which holds a site's configuration.

While this combination works and the sites appears fine on web, I have a feeling that my code doesn't follow the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) standard.

```
server {
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # notes {
        # 443 ssl http2;
        # [::]:443 ssl http2;
    # }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name contfix.co.il www.contfix.co.il;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/contfix.co.il.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/contfix.co.il.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    root /var/www/html/contfix.co.il;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

    location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }
}
```

Given that my code seems to be a bit repetitive, I want to ask: Can it be made a bit less repetitive?

Comment: This works?  Because your second server block is listening on port 80 and also using an SSL certificate.  Either you mean to be listening on port 443 or you want to remove the lines about the SSL configuration (I think)

Comment: These are just comfortable comment because later I would have to use this syntax.

Comment: Was there anything else you hoped my answer might suggest?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I didn't recall I putted two similar confs in one code block (maybe by mistake). I think there weren't other parts and the purpose at the time was to use just one big file for everything, something I later found out impossible with Nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [compared the two server configurations](https://www.diffchecker.com/0oKtoUOA) and the only thing that appears to match between the two is the `location ~ \.php$` directive, as well as the `index` directive, though in the latter configuration that is under the directive `location /`

[image: nginx config diff]

Perhaps the common configurations could be put into the file included via [`include`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) (i.e. `fastcgi-php.conf`).